# SignalR/hubs still downloading

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have an ASP.NET MVC app and i use SignalR. I did the installation, everything was clear. But when i run the website, it still downloading some .js and particulary signalr/hubs. So the website never end loading. When i open in a new tab signalr/hubs the .js file appears, so it's downloaded, but the website still download this file. Here what i have :

On the Hub

```
public class Notifier : Hub 
{ 
  public void NotifyAllUsers(Notification message) { 
      Clients.All.Broadcast(message); 
  } 
}
```

On the View :

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/View/Platform/signalRPlatform.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/View/Platform/Platform.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
}
```

On Startup

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
```

Any solution?

It's the same thing if i change

```
<script src="~/signalr/js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question rather than using an image

Comment: I posted code above

Comment: What other javascript are you trying to download?  The jquery.signalR-2.2.3.js is the only SignalR js file you need.

Comment: signalr/hubs as a javascript. this file block everything

Comment: How big is the file? What does it contain?  Does it contain your code? You already have everything you need to use SignalR,

Comment: When i delete the row which call "~/signalr/hubs" script, the website is not blocked but i can't use signalR. When i call the script, the website is blocked

Comment: Oh, is this the file that has the connection.start() command?  This will stay connected and show 'Pending' because SignalR uses a persistent WebSocket connection.  Shouldn't block the website from working though.

Comment: yes this file ! do you have any solution ?

Comment: It should show a connection that never ends, is that what you are seeing.

Comment: i don't see anything, because all .js that are after this .js (signalR/hubs) are never downloaded so never read

Comment: Your setup must be different than mine because I never downloaded another .js file, I just put this in my existing page.                                 // SignalR connection to get Alert updates.
    var connection = $.hubConnection();
    var hub = connection.createHubProxy("AlertNotifierHub");

    hub.on("notifyAlerts", function () {
        alerts.BindAlerts();
    });

    hub.on("dismissAlerts", function (employeeID) {
        if (alerts.EmployeeID == employeeID) {
            alerts.BindAlerts();
        }
    });

    connection.logging = true;
    connection.start();

Comment: well i don't know, i also created a new project just to test signalR but i have the same problem. I'm using Visual Studio in Mac but i don't think that's the problem

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser Console?

Comment: No nothing, the page still loading. I also downloaded a Tutorial Project from C#-Corner but i have the same problem. So i don't really know where the problem comes from

Comment: I never referenced ~/signalR/hubs although if I go to that location on my website I see a javascript file.  I might have had the same issue as you and just didn't use it, it is called the generated proxy and is not required.  Without that reference the little bit of js I included in my earlier comment allowed my client to get connected and receive messages from the server.  I used this page to setup https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#establishconnection

Comment: I tried what you say : not referencing ~/signalR/hubs and that's true. When i go to this location domain.com/signalr/hubs the .js is here.
But when i want to use signalR i have an error in the console : Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>.